# form input focus in/out

Tags: jquery, focus, focusout

i have some login forms, and if one sets its email to be remembered, it will be pre filled in the email input.
i want that, if one clicks on the email input, the content (the actual email) to fade, but if he clicks out, the email to show again. 
but i just managed to make the email fade out,i don;t know hot to restore the old value on focus out. the code:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
         $('input').focus(function() {
         $(this).val("");
         });
         $('input').focusout(function() {
         $(this).val();
   });
   });
```

any idea about what should be the value of focus out so that the old remembered value (the email) to appear there?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually save the "default" value in the title attribute of the field, so that it can easily retrieved on blur:

```
$('.placeholder').live('focus', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('title') ) $(this).val('');
});
$('.placeholder').live('blur', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ) $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: Nice idea, but in that case you'd better use data() function to store data

Comment: Actually - and please, correct me if I'm wrong - I think that the title is a quite good place to store this type of data. The text used as a placeholder serves a guide to the user, and having this text appear on mouse over (standard functionality in most browsers) is actually a positive thing, at least in my eyes. Also; I see no point in adding the overhead of running jquery functions if unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think so, reading from w3schools i find: `The title attribute is often used with form and a elements, to provide information about input formats and link destinations. It is also a required attribute for the abbr and acronym elements.` and so saving an email doesn't seem to me a very good idea, but honestly i don't think you are doing anything wrong! :)

Comment: Sorry - I see now that I should have been more specific in my answer. My "default" value stored in the title is just that: info about the format or a clarification of the label, rather than an acceptable value. For a standard login field (with the label "Email adress:"), I might put title="user@youdomain.com" or similar - this value is of course not accepted when submitting the field.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         var oldemail;
         $('input').focus(function() {
            oldemail = $(this).val();
            $(this).val("");
         });
         $('input').focusout(function() {
             $(this).val(oldemail);
         });
   });
```

(just one thing: this does exactly what you want i think, but it doesn't make much sense to me!)

Answer (score 0):

there is no function in jquery as focusout. U can use blur instead..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).val("");
     });
     $('input').blur(function() {
        $(this).val();
     });
});
```